# Curl not binding to outgoing interface despite setting CURLOPT_INTERFACE

Tags: php, iis, curl, windows-server-2012-r2

Site is on IIS 8, PHP 5.6.10.

Trying to load a website using a specific interface on a webserver (two interfaces on different WANs).

```
<?php
    curl_setopt($foo, CURLOPT_INTERFACE,'192.168.30.113');
    $foo = curl_init('http://example.net');
    $bar = curl_exec($foo);
    echo $bar
?>
```

I've tried both the Windows interface name `VPN` along with the internal assigned IP address `192.168.30.113` for `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`, both to no avail - the page is always loaded on the server's "highest priority" NIC.  The website is properly bound in IIS to the correct IP/NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've figured this out by now but since it's still here unanswered...

You're setting `curl_setopt` before initializing the curl handle. You need to call curl_init() first, then curl_setopt(), then curl_exec().